# Shader fails on mobile

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader, webgl

This shader works on laptop but for some reason it keeps failing on mobile I assume i'm doing something wrong with the precision but i don't know what here is the error:

> THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error: 0 35715 false gl.getProgramInfoLog
> invalid shaders THREE.WebGLShader: gl.getShaderInfoLog() fragment
> 0:434: S0032: no default precision defined for variable 'float[4]'1:
> #version 300 es 2: #define varying in 3: out highp vec4 pc_fragColor;

and here is the shader code in the js tab:
https://codepen.io/uiunicorn/pen/QWQrQBB

full:

```
export const terrain_shader = (function() {

  const _VS_1 = `

// Triplanar Attributes
in vec4 weights1;
in vec4 weights2;

// Outputs
out vec3 vCoords;
out vec4 vWeights1;
out vec4 vWeights2;


`;


    const _VS_2 = `

vCoords = transformed.xyz;
vWeights1 = weights1;
vWeights2 = weights2;

`;

  const _VS = `

// Attributes
in vec3 coords;
in vec3 color;
in vec4 weights1;
in vec4 weights2;

// Outputs
out vec2 vUV;
out vec4 vColor;
out vec3 vNormal;
out vec3 vCoords;
out vec4 vWeights1;
out vec4 vWeights2;

void main(){
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

  vUV = uv;
  vNormal = normal;

  vColor = vec4(color, 1);
  vCoords = position.xyz;
  vWeights1 = weights1;
  vWeights2 = weights2;
}
  `;
  

  const _PS = `

precision highp float;
precision highp int;
precision highp sampler2DArray;

uniform sampler2DArray TRIPLANAR_normalMap;
uniform sampler2DArray TRIPLANAR_diffuseMap;
uniform sampler2D TRIPLANAR_noiseMap;

in vec3 vCoords;
in vec4 vWeights1;
in vec4 vWeights2;


const float _TRI_SCALE = 10.0;

float sum( vec3 v ) { return v.x+v.y+v.z; }

vec4 hash4( vec2 p ) {
  return fract(
    sin(vec4(1.0+dot(p,vec2(37.0,17.0)), 
              2.0+dot(p,vec2(11.0,47.0)),
              3.0+dot(p,vec2(41.0,29.0)),
              4.0+dot(p,vec2(23.0,31.0))))*103.0);
}

vec4 _TerrainBlend_4(vec4 samples[4]) {
  float depth = 0.2;
  float ma = max(
      samples[0].w,
      max(
          samples[1].w,
          max(samples[2].w, samples[3].w))) - depth;

  float b1 = max(samples[0].w - ma, 0.0);
  float b2 = max(samples[1].w - ma, 0.0);
  float b3 = max(samples[2].w - ma, 0.0);
  float b4 = max(samples[3].w - ma, 0.0);

  vec4 numer = (
      samples[0] * b1 + samples[1] * b2 +
      samples[2] * b3 + samples[3] * b4);
  float denom = (b1 + b2 + b3 + b4);
  return numer / denom;
}

vec4 _TerrainBlend_4_lerp(vec4 samples[4]) {
  return (
      samples[0] * samples[0].w + samples[1] * samples[1].w +
      samples[2] * samples[2].w + samples[3] * samples[3].w);
}

// Lifted from https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Xtl3zf
vec4 texture_UV(in sampler2DArray srcTexture, in vec3 x) {
  float k = texture(TRIPLANAR_noiseMap, 0.0025*x.xy).x; // cheap (cache friendly) lookup
  float l = k*8.0;
  float f = fract(l);
  
  float ia = floor(l+0.5); // suslik's method (see comments)
  float ib = floor(l);
  f = min(f, 1.0-f)*2.0;

  vec2 offa = sin(vec2(3.0,7.0)*ia); // can replace with any other hash
  vec2 offb = sin(vec2(3.0,7.0)*ib); // can replace with any other hash

  vec4 cola = texture(srcTexture, vec3(x.xy + offa, x.z));
  vec4 colb = texture(srcTexture, vec3(x.xy + offb, x.z));

  return mix(cola, colb, smoothstep(0.2,0.8,f-0.1*sum(cola.xyz-colb.xyz)));
}

vec4 _Triplanar_UV(vec3 pos, vec3 normal, float texSlice, sampler2DArray tex) {
  vec4 dx = texture_UV(tex, vec3(pos.zy / _TRI_SCALE, texSlice));
  vec4 dy = texture_UV(tex, vec3(pos.xz / _TRI_SCALE, texSlice));
  vec4 dz = texture_UV(tex, vec3(pos.xy / _TRI_SCALE, texSlice));

  vec3 weights = abs(normal.xyz);
  weights = weights / (weights.x + weights.y + weights.z);

  return dx * weights.x + dy * weights.y + dz * weights.z;
}

vec4 _TriplanarN_UV(vec3 pos, vec3 normal, float texSlice, sampler2DArray tex) {
  // Tangent Reconstruction
  // Triplanar uvs
  vec2 uvX = pos.zy; // x facing plane
  vec2 uvY = pos.xz; // y facing plane
  vec2 uvZ = pos.xy; // z facing plane
  // Tangent space normal maps
  vec3 tx = texture_UV(tex, vec3(uvX / _TRI_SCALE, texSlice)).xyz * vec3(2,2,2) - vec3(1,1,1);
  vec3 ty = texture_UV(tex, vec3(uvY / _TRI_SCALE, texSlice)).xyz * vec3(2,2,2) - vec3(1,1,1);
  vec3 tz = texture_UV(tex, vec3(uvZ / _TRI_SCALE, texSlice)).xyz * vec3(2,2,2) - vec3(1,1,1);

  vec3 weights = abs(normal.xyz);
  weights = weights / (weights.x + weights.y + weights.z);

  // Get the sign (-1 or 1) of the surface normal
  vec3 axis = sign(normal);
  // Construct tangent to world matrices for each axis
  vec3 tangentX = normalize(cross(normal, vec3(0.0, axis.x, 0.0)));
  vec3 bitangentX = normalize(cross(tangentX, normal)) * axis.x;
  mat3 tbnX = mat3(tangentX, bitangentX, normal);

  vec3 tangentY = normalize(cross(normal, vec3(0.0, 0.0, axis.y)));
  vec3 bitangentY = normalize(cross(tangentY, normal)) * axis.y;
  mat3 tbnY = mat3(tangentY, bitangentY, normal);

  vec3 tangentZ = normalize(cross(normal, vec3(0.0, -axis.z, 0.0)));
  vec3 bitangentZ = normalize(-cross(tangentZ, normal)) * axis.z;
  mat3 tbnZ = mat3(tangentZ, bitangentZ, normal);

  // Apply tangent to world matrix and triblend
  // Using clamp() because the cross products may be NANs
  vec3 worldNormal = normalize(
      clamp(tbnX * tx, -1.0, 1.0) * weights.x +
      clamp(tbnY * ty, -1.0, 1.0) * weights.y +
      clamp(tbnZ * tz, -1.0, 1.0) * weights.z
      );
  return vec4(worldNormal, 0.0);
}

vec4 _Triplanar(vec3 pos, vec3 normal, float texSlice, sampler2DArray tex) {
  vec4 dx = texture(tex, vec3(pos.zy / _TRI_SCALE, texSlice));
  vec4 dy = texture(tex, vec3(pos.xz / _TRI_SCALE, texSlice));
  vec4 dz = texture(tex, vec3(pos.xy / _TRI_SCALE, texSlice));

  vec3 weights = abs(normal.xyz);
  weights = weights / (weights.x + weights.y + weights.z);

  return dx * weights.x + dy * weights.y + dz * weights.z;
}

vec4 _TriplanarN(vec3 pos, vec3 normal, float texSlice, sampler2DArray tex) {
  vec2 uvx = pos.zy;
  vec2 uvy = pos.xz;
  vec2 uvz = pos.xy;
  vec3 tx = texture(tex, vec3(uvx / _TRI_SCALE, texSlice)).xyz * vec3(2,2,2) - vec3(1,1,1);
  vec3 ty = texture(tex, vec3(uvy / _TRI_SCALE, texSlice)).xyz * vec3(2,2,2) - vec3(1,1,1);
  vec3 tz = texture(tex, vec3(uvz / _TRI_SCALE, texSlice)).xyz * vec3(2,2,2) - vec3(1,1,1);

  vec3 weights = abs(normal.xyz);
  weights *= weights;
  weights = weights / (weights.x + weights.y + weights.z);

  vec3 axis = sign(normal);
  vec3 tangentX = normalize(cross(normal, vec3(0.0, axis.x, 0.0)));
  vec3 bitangentX = normalize(cross(tangentX, normal)) * axis.x;
  mat3 tbnX = mat3(tangentX, bitangentX, normal);

  vec3 tangentY = normalize(cross(normal, vec3(0.0, 0.0, axis.y)));
  vec3 bitangentY = normalize(cross(tangentY, normal)) * axis.y;
  mat3 tbnY = mat3(tangentY, bitangentY, normal);

  vec3 tangentZ = normalize(cross(normal, vec3(0.0, -axis.z, 0.0)));
  vec3 bitangentZ = normalize(-cross(tangentZ, normal)) * axis.z;
  mat3 tbnZ = mat3(tangentZ, bitangentZ, normal);

  vec3 worldNormal = normalize(
      clamp(tbnX * tx, -1.0, 1.0) * weights.x +
      clamp(tbnY * ty, -1.0, 1.0) * weights.y +
      clamp(tbnZ * tz, -1.0, 1.0) * weights.z);
  return vec4(worldNormal, 0.0);
}

void main() {
  vec3 worldPosition = vCoords;

  float weightIndices[4] = float[4](vWeights1.x, vWeights1.y, vWeights1.z, vWeights1.w);
  float weightValues[4] = float[4](vWeights2.x, vWeights2.y, vWeights2.z, vWeights2.w);

  // TRIPLANAR SPLATTING w/ NORMALS & UVS
  vec3 worldSpaceNormal = normalize(vNormal);
  vec4 diffuseSamples[4];
  vec4 normalSamples[4];

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    vec4 d = vec4(0.0);
    vec4 n = vec4(0.0);
    if (weightValues[i] > 0.0) {
      d = _Triplanar_UV(
        worldPosition, worldSpaceNormal, weightIndices[i], TRIPLANAR_diffuseMap);
      n = _TriplanarN_UV(
        worldPosition, worldSpaceNormal, weightIndices[i], TRIPLANAR_normalMap);

      d.w *= weightValues[i];
      n.w = d.w;
    }

    diffuseSamples[i] = d;
    normalSamples[i] = n;
  }

  vec4 diffuseBlended = _TerrainBlend_4(diffuseSamples);
  vec4 normalBlended = _TerrainBlend_4(normalSamples);
  vec3 diffuse = diffuseBlended.xyz;

  vec3 finalColour = diffuse;

  // finalColour = vec3(sin(worldPosition.x), sin(worldPosition.y), sin(worldPosition.z));

  gl_FragColor = vec4(finalColour, 1);
}

  `;


  const _PS_1 = `

precision mediump sampler2DArray;

uniform sampler2DArray TRIPLANAR_normalMap;
uniform sampler2DArray TRIPLANAR_diffuseMap;
uniform sampler2D TRIPLANAR_noiseMap;

in vec3 vCoords;
in vec4 vWeights1;
in vec4 vWeights2;


const float _TRI_SCALE = 10.0;

float sum( vec3 v ) { return v.x+v.y+v.z; }

vec4 hash4( vec2 p ) {
  return fract(
    sin(vec4(1.0+dot(p,vec2(37.0,17.0)), 
              2.0+dot(p,vec2(11.0,47.0)),
              3.0+dot(p,vec2(41.0,29.0)),
              4.0+dot(p,vec2(23.0,31.0))))*103.0);
}

vec4 _TerrainBlend_4(vec4 samples[4]) {
  float depth = 0.2;
  float ma = max(
      samples[0].w,
      max(
          samples[1].w,
          max(samples[2].w, samples[3].w))) - depth;

  float b1 = max(samples[0].w - ma, 0.0);
  float b2 = max(samples[1].w - ma, 0.0);
  float b3 = max(samples[2].w - ma, 0.0);
  float b4 = max(samples[3].w - ma, 0.0);

  vec4 numer = (
      samples[0] * b1 + samples[1] * b2 +
      samples[2] * b3 + samples[3] * b4);
  float denom = (b1 + b2 + b3 + b4);
  return numer / denom;
}

vec4 _TerrainBlend_4_lerp(vec4 samples[4]) {
  return (
      samples[0] * samples[0].w + samples[1] * samples[1].w +
      samples[2] * samples[2].w + samples[3] * samples[3].w);
}

// Lifted from https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Xtl3zf
vec4 texture_UV(in sampler2DArray srcTexture, in vec3 x) {
  float k = texture(TRIPLANAR_noiseMap, 0.0025*x.xy).x; // cheap (cache friendly) lookup
  float l = k*8.0;
  float f = fract(l);
  
  float ia = floor(l+0.5); // suslik's method (see comments)
  float ib = floor(l);
  f = min(f, 1.0-f)*2.0;

  vec2 offa = sin(vec2(3.0,7.0)*ia); // can replace with any other hash
  vec2 offb = sin(vec2(3.0,7.0)*ib); // can replace with any other hash

  vec4 cola = texture(srcTexture, vec3(x.xy + offa, x.z));
  vec4 colb = texture(srcTexture, vec3(x.xy + offb, x.z));

  return mix(cola, colb, smoothstep(0.2,0.8,f-0.1*sum(cola.xyz-colb.xyz)));
}

vec4 _Triplanar_UV(vec3 pos, vec3 normal, float texSlice, sampler2DArray tex) {
  vec4 dx = texture_UV(tex, vec3(pos.zy / _TRI_SCALE, texSlice));
  vec4 dy = texture_UV(tex, vec3(pos.xz / _TRI_SCALE, texSlice));
  vec4 dz = texture_UV(tex, vec3(pos.xy / _TRI_SCALE, texSlice));

  vec3 weights = abs(normal.xyz);
  weights = weights / (weights.x + weights.y + weights.z);

  return dx * weights.x + dy * weights.y + dz * weights.z;
}

vec4 _TriplanarN_UV(vec3 pos, vec3 normal, float texSlice, sampler2DArray tex) {
  // Tangent Reconstruction
  // Triplanar uvs
  vec2 uvX = pos.zy; // x facing plane
  vec2 uvY = pos.xz; // y facing plane
  vec2 uvZ = pos.xy; // z facing plane
  // Tangent space normal maps
  vec3 tx = texture_UV(tex, vec3(uvX / _TRI_SCALE, texSlice)).xyz * vec3(2,2,2) - vec3(1,1,1);
  vec3 ty = texture_UV(tex, vec3(uvY / _TRI_SCALE, texSlice)).xyz * vec3(2,2,2) - vec3(1,1,1);
  vec3 tz = texture_UV(tex, vec3(uvZ / _TRI_SCALE, texSlice)).xyz * vec3(2,2,2) - vec3(1,1,1);

  vec3 weights = abs(normal.xyz);
  weights = weights / (weights.x + weights.y + weights.z);

  // Get the sign (-1 or 1) of the surface normal
  vec3 axis = sign(normal);
  // Construct tangent to world matrices for each axis
  vec3 tangentX = normalize(cross(normal, vec3(0.0, axis.x, 0.0)));
  vec3 bitangentX = normalize(cross(tangentX, normal)) * axis.x;
  mat3 tbnX = mat3(tangentX, bitangentX, normal);

  vec3 tangentY = normalize(cross(normal, vec3(0.0, 0.0, axis.y)));
  vec3 bitangentY = normalize(cross(tangentY, normal)) * axis.y;
  mat3 tbnY = mat3(tangentY, bitangentY, normal);

  vec3 tangentZ = normalize(cross(normal, vec3(0.0, -axis.z, 0.0)));
  vec3 bitangentZ = normalize(-cross(tangentZ, normal)) * axis.z;
  mat3 tbnZ = mat3(tangentZ, bitangentZ, normal);

  // Apply tangent to world matrix and triblend
  // Using clamp() because the cross products may be NANs
  vec3 worldNormal = normalize(
      clamp(tbnX * tx, -1.0, 1.0) * weights.x +
      clamp(tbnY * ty, -1.0, 1.0) * weights.y +
      clamp(tbnZ * tz, -1.0, 1.0) * weights.z
      );
  return vec4(worldNormal, 0.0);
}

vec4 _Triplanar(vec3 pos, vec3 normal, float texSlice, sampler2DArray tex) {
  vec4 dx = texture(tex, vec3(pos.zy / _TRI_SCALE, texSlice));
  vec4 dy = texture(tex, vec3(pos.xz / _TRI_SCALE, texSlice));
  vec4 dz = texture(tex, vec3(pos.xy / _TRI_SCALE, texSlice));

  vec3 weights = abs(normal.xyz);
  weights = weights / (weights.x + weights.y + weights.z);

  return dx * weights.x + dy * weights.y + dz * weights.z;
}

vec4 _TriplanarN(vec3 pos, vec3 normal, float texSlice, sampler2DArray tex) {
  vec2 uvx = pos.zy;
  vec2 uvy = pos.xz;
  vec2 uvz = pos.xy;
  vec3 tx = texture(tex, vec3(uvx / _TRI_SCALE, texSlice)).xyz * vec3(2,2,2) - vec3(1,1,1);
  vec3 ty = texture(tex, vec3(uvy / _TRI_SCALE, texSlice)).xyz * vec3(2,2,2) - vec3(1,1,1);
  vec3 tz = texture(tex, vec3(uvz / _TRI_SCALE, texSlice)).xyz * vec3(2,2,2) - vec3(1,1,1);

  vec3 weights = abs(normal.xyz);
  weights *= weights;
  weights = weights / (weights.x + weights.y + weights.z);

  vec3 axis = sign(normal);
  vec3 tangentX = normalize(cross(normal, vec3(0.0, axis.x, 0.0)));
  vec3 bitangentX = normalize(cross(tangentX, normal)) * axis.x;
  mat3 tbnX = mat3(tangentX, bitangentX, normal);

  vec3 tangentY = normalize(cross(normal, vec3(0.0, 0.0, axis.y)));
  vec3 bitangentY = normalize(cross(tangentY, normal)) * axis.y;
  mat3 tbnY = mat3(tangentY, bitangentY, normal);

  vec3 tangentZ = normalize(cross(normal, vec3(0.0, -axis.z, 0.0)));
  vec3 bitangentZ = normalize(-cross(tangentZ, normal)) * axis.z;
  mat3 tbnZ = mat3(tangentZ, bitangentZ, normal);

  vec3 worldNormal = normalize(
      clamp(tbnX * tx, -1.0, 1.0) * weights.x +
      clamp(tbnY * ty, -1.0, 1.0) * weights.y +
      clamp(tbnZ * tz, -1.0, 1.0) * weights.z);
  return vec4(worldNormal, 0.0);
}

  `;
  
    const _PS_2 = `

{
  vec3 worldPosition = vCoords;

  float weightIndices[4] = float[4](vWeights1.x, vWeights1.y, vWeights1.z, vWeights1.w);
  float weightValues[4] = float[4](vWeights2.x, vWeights2.y, vWeights2.z, vWeights2.w);
  
  // TRIPLANAR SPLATTING w/ NORMALS & UVS
  vec3 worldSpaceNormal = normalize(vNormal);
  vec4 diffuseSamples[4];
  // vec4 normalSamples[4];
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    vec4 d = vec4(0.0);
    // vec4 n = vec4(0.0);
    if (weightValues[i] > 0.0) {
      d = _Triplanar_UV(
          worldPosition, worldSpaceNormal, weightIndices[i], TRIPLANAR_diffuseMap);
      // n = _TriplanarN_UV(
      //     worldPosition, worldSpaceNormal, weightIndices[i], TRIPLANAR_normalMap);
  
      d.w *= weightValues[i];
      // n.w = d.w;
    }
  
    diffuseSamples[i] = d;
    // normalSamples[i] = n;
  }
  
  vec4 diffuseBlended = _TerrainBlend_4(diffuseSamples);
  // vec4 normalBlended = _TerrainBlend_4(normalSamples);
  diffuseColor = sRGBToLinear(diffuseBlended);
  // normal = normalBlended.xyz;
}

    `;

    return {
      VS: _VS,
      PS: _PS,
      VS1: _VS_1,
      VS2: _VS_2,
      PS1: _PS_1,
      PS2: _PS_2,
    };
  })();
```

thanks for reading

update I have tried adding:

```
precision mediump sampler2DArray;

precision mediump float; 
precision mediump int;   

uniform sampler2DArray TRIPLANAR_normalMap;
uniform sampler2DArray TRIPLANAR_diffuseMap;
uniform sampler2D TRIPLANAR_noiseMap;
```

to: const _PS_1 and _PS still the error persists
doing this also throw a new error:

> Uniforms with the same name but different type/precision

i was able to make this error go away by adding:

```
precision mediump float;
```

to the vertex shaders but i'm still left with the original error of:

```
no default precision defined for variable 'float[4]'1
```

**UPDATE**

tried adding

```
renderer.precision="mediump";
```

and lowp this had no effect

i've also notice the texture of the ground which is the same problem on mobile well it will not show up.. and i get the same issue in firefox the browser its working in correctly is chrome,

here is the site:
http://wonder-3d.hol.es/ADz(1)z/115(1)

here is the shader file:
http://wonder-3d.hol.es/ADz(1)z/src/terrain-shader.js

small issue with chrome:
In chrome if i have dev tools open and close it before the the ground texture has loaded the texture will not show up like in firefox and mobile but that's only if you do that with dev tools exactly, if you don't it works fine... so it's not a big issue i can make the terrain texture show up again by re-opening dev tools though and everything works as intended.

thanks for any help.

Comment: I see you've opened a bounty for this question. Did my answer not fix your problem? If that's the case, what problem did you encounter after defining the precision?

Comment: Hi so i added precision mediump float; to each fragment shader as well as the uniform's, int and sampler but the error still says no default precision defined for variable 'float[4]'1

Comment: I think it would be easier to debug if your codepen example was executable, instead of just the standalone shader text. Could you share a working demo that’s already set up with the materials and renderer so others can debug it? See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

That error is saying `no default precision defined` because you're not defining a precision at the beginning of your shader code.

Make sure that each finished shader includes `precision highp float;` at the beginning of each when it gets assigned to a material. You've broken the shaders up in what appears to be several separate files, so it's hard to tell where exactly it should go, just make sure it's at the beginning.

Comment: does it matter if its highp, med or lowp? for mobiles?

Comment: @user3112634 I’ve always used highp. Not sure if it matters, but you could read up on precision best-practices here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/WebGL_best_practices#be_precise_with_glsl_precision_annotations

Comment: i've updated the question with a live link

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue as you on certain Android phones (Android 12). It has to do with the way you're initializing your arrays `weightIndices` and `weightValues`.

**Replace:**

```c
float weightIndices[4] = float[4](vWeights1.x, vWeights1.y, vWeights1.z, vWeights1.w);
```

**With (same for weightValues):**

```c
float weightIndices[4];
weightIndices[0] = vWeights1.x;
weightIndices[1] = vWeights1.y;
weightIndices[2] = vWeights1.z;
weightIndices[3] = vWeights1.w;
```

Comment: sadly this didn't work for my case

Comment: Sorry, it didn't help. In my case, I didn't need to define the precision. By the way, you have two definitions for the above-mentionned arrays in _PS and _PS2, did you replace both?

Answer (score 1):

**OpenGL** specification doesn't define precision qualifier for fragment shaders, this means you should define it by yourself.

You should add these two lines to your shader code under **const _PS_1**  declaration:

```
precision highp float; // Define float precision
precision highp int;   // Define int precision
```

resulting in the following:

```
const _PS_1 = `
precision mediump sampler2DArray;

precision highp float; // Define float precision
precision highp int;   // Define int precision

uniform sampler2DArray TRIPLANAR_normalMap;
uniform sampler2DArray TRIPLANAR_diffuseMap;
uniform sampler2D TRIPLANAR_noiseMap;

in vec3 vCoords;
in vec4 vWeights1;
in vec4 vWeights2;
```

For good performance, always use the lowest precision that is
possible. This is especially important on lower-end hardware. Good
rules of thumb are:

> - For world space positions and texture coordinates, use **highp float ** precision.
> - For everything else (vectors, HDR colors, etc.), start with **mediump float ** precision. Increase only if necessary.

Comment: add what you have suggested it still throws the same error maybe this is a device problem.. ?

Comment: What is your device?

Comment: Tested on Galaxy s8 on chrome with precision mediump float;

Comment: What about  _PS_2? Try adding qualifier there as well. What is your device’s cpu and gpu?

Comment: yes i added precision mediump sampler2DArray;

precision mediump float; 
precision mediump int; to _PS_2 if i try adding the uniform's it throws this: ERROR: 0:1420: 'uniform' : only allowed at global scope
ERROR: 0:1420: 'uniform' : Local variables can only use the const storage qualifier.

Comment: Looks like it's a bug. Have you tried testing this shader on a different device or browser?

Comment: yes this only happens on mobile

Comment: Yusifi i've updated the question firefox is also an issue

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I opened your site in my browser and it runs very slow even on my MacBook M1 Max. Try to simplify your shaders or change to another less expensive ones.